# Regex: Delete the contents of all files that start, the first line, with the word ETICHETE:

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text

I want to use Regex to delete the contents of all files that start with the word `ETICHETE`:

For example, all my files starts, the first line, like this:

```
Eticheta: Semifinala GBOB Crisana - Revista De Muzica Online:
```

```
Eticheta: bunica merge la cumparaturi cu fratele ei:
```

I want to delete al files that starts with the word `Eticheta:`

My regex is not working, don't know why:

- **FIND:** `^\AEticheta:.*$`
- **REPLACE BY:** `(leave empty)`

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(^\AEticheta:)([\s\S]+)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: `^` before `\A` is useless as well as capture groups and `Check wrap around` and `Uncheck . matches newlines`.

Comment: you can add your own solution as answer, as an alternative, if is different